# How to set minimum height of row in prawn Table cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, styles, prawn

I can set height for row. But it is fixed height. if content increases height does not increase automatically. just clip extra content.

Here is my code. how can i set default height 20 not fixed height

```
pdf.table([applicant_data],
              :cell_style => {
                  :inline_format => true,
                  :padding => [3, 3,3,3], :size => 9,
                  :border_widths => [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                  :height => 20,
                  #:font_style => :bold
              },
:column_widths => {0 => 30, 1 => 110, 2 => 50, 3 => 110, 4 =>  col_wid_bo })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting height dynamically based on string length. If string fits in one line the default height , if not not increase height based on string length. That's it.

Comment: How did you get the length of the string from a specific attribute in a given row...and use that length in the table settings?

Answer (score 1):

In the table block, you can set the row height:

```
pdf.table data do
    rows(0..-1).each do |r|
        r.height = 25 if r.height < 25
    end
end
```